# IValidatableObject not triggered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-validation, ivalidatableobject

I'm trying to make use of the IValidatableObject as described here http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2010/12/31/ASPNETMVC3ValidationIValidatableObject.aspx.

But it just wont fire when I'm trying to validate, the `ModelState.IsValid` is always `true`.

Here is my model code:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(RegistrationMetaData))]
public partial class Registration : DefaultModel
{
    [Editable(false)]
    [Display(Name = "Property one")]
    public int PropertyOne { get; set; }
}

public class RegistrationMetaData :IValidatableObject
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer no. is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Customer no.")]
    public string CustomerNo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Comments")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (new AccountModel().GetProfile(CustomerNo) == null)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Customer no. is not valid.", new[] { "CustomerNo" });
    }
}
```

I extend a LINQ to SQL table called `Registration`, my first guess was that this is not possible to do on a Meta class, but I'm not sure?

I do not get any errors, and it builds just fine, but the `Validate` method will not fire. What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it is the `Registration` model that should implement `IValidatableObject` and not `RegistrationMetaData`:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(RegistrationMetaData))]
public partial class Registration : IValidatableObject
{
    [Editable(false)]
    [Display(Name = "Property one")]
    public int PropertyOne { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (new AccountModel().GetProfile(CustomerNo) == null)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Customer no. is not valid.", new[] { "CustomerNo" });
    }
}

public class RegistrationMetaData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer no. is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Customer no.")]
    public string CustomerNo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Comments")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thought it was something like that. My problem is that I inherit from `DefaultModel` on `Registration`, and as far as I know I cant inherit from more than one class. How can I solve that?

Comment: @Martin, you can inherit from a single class but you can implement as many interfaces as you like. `IValidatableObject` is an interface.

Comment: Will this work even if I use it with a private sealed class that I put my data annotations? Reason being it was a database first.