# IValidatableObject not firing upon form submission

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, .net-core, ivalidatableobject

I'm new to .net and am attempting to write some slick custom validation for a `CustomerInfo` form that I'm submitting.  To do this, I'm implementing IValidatableObject on the model class and following [this template from microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#ivalidatableobject).

However, no matter what, I cannot get this to trigger.  At this point, I've removed any conditionals from the Validate method just to see if I can get it to fire on a submission.  I should note that above the `Validate` method, I see that vsCode has a "0 References" note that seems suspicious.  What might I be missing?

I have looked into a few similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502808/ivalidatableobject-not-triggered) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662801/ivalidatableobject-validate-method-not-working)  The first is not the same situation and I'm sufficiently new to the framework that I can't tell if the second is.

Below is the model to which I'm referring.  This is the only file that I have modified to accommodate the IValidatableObject:

```
using CS_Test.Mappers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CS_Test.Models
{
    public class CustomerInfo : IValidatableObject
    {
        public string ServiceType {get; set;}
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName {get; set;}
        [DisplayName("Middle")]
        public string MiddleName {get; set;}
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string LastName {get; set;}
        public string BusinessName {get; set;}
        [Required]
        [StringLength(9, ErrorMessage = "Tax id must be 9 digits.")]
        [DisplayName("Tax Id")]
        public string TaxId {get; set;}
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Security Password")]
        public string SecurityPassword {get; set;}
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Date Of Birth")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth {get; set;}
        public string auto_generate_loginField {get; set;}
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", 
        ErrorMessage = "Not a valid email.")]
        [DisplayName("Email Address")]
        public string Email {get; set;}
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Phone number must be 10 digits.")] 
        [DisplayName("Phone Number")]
        public string Phone {get; set;}
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Address")]
        public string Address1Field {get; set;}
        [DisplayName("Address2")]
        public string Address2Field {get; set;}
        [Required]
        public string City {get; set;}
        [Required]
        public string State {get; set;}
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Zip Code")]
        public string Zip {get; set;}

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(
                "Test test test",
                new[] { nameof(FirstName)});
        }
    }
}
```

And (for what it's worth) here's the form that I'm submitting.

```
@model Models.CustomerInfo

<form asp-controller="ServiceOrder" asp-action="CreatePost" class="row g-3" id="customerInfoForm" method="post">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="serviceType" id="residentialService" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label">Residential</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="serviceType" id="businessService">
        <label class="form-check-label">Business</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-12 residentialOnly">
        <label class="requiredField">Name</label>
        <div class="row" id="personName">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="FirstName" placeholder="First" required>
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="FirstName"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="MiddleName" placeholder="Middle">
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="MiddleName"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="LastName" placeholder="Last" required>
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="LastName"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 businessOnly">
        <label class="requiredField" asp-for="LastName">Business Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="LastName" required>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="LastName"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="requiredField" asp-for="SecurityPassword">Security Password</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="SecurityPassword" required>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="SecurityPassword"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="requiredField" asp-for="TaxId">Tax Id</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="TaxId" required>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="TaxId"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="requiredField" asp-for="DateOfBirth">Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" asp-for="DateOfBirth" required>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="requiredField" asp-for="Email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" asp-for="Email" required>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Email"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="requiredField" asp-for="Phone">Phone</label>
        <input type="phone" class="form-control" asp-for="Phone" required>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Phone"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
        <label class="form-label requiredField" asp-for="Address1Field">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Address1Field" placeholder="1234 Main St" required>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Address1Field"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12">
        <label class="form-label" asp-for="Address2Field">Address 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Address2Field" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Address2Field"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="form-label requiredField" asp-for="City">City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="City" required>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="City"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="form-label requiredField" asp-for="State">State</label>
        <div>
            <select id="inputCustomerState" class="form-select" style="width: 100%" asp-for="State" required>
            </select>
        </div>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="State"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="form-label requiredField" asp-for="Zip">Zip</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Zip" required>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Zip"></span>
    </div>
    
</form>

<script>
    newForm = $("#customerInfoForm");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(newForm);
</script>
```

**By popular request, my controller methods**

Used to render the form:

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var newOrderId = HttpContext.Session.Get<Guid>("NewOrderId");
        if (newOrderId == Guid.Empty) { newOrderId = NewOrderId(); } // if no order id was found, then create one
        ViewBag.NewOrderId = newOrderId;
        NewCustomerOrder order = GetNewCustomerOrder(newOrderId);
        return View(order);
    }
```

To Submit the form via ajax:

```
public IActionResult Review(CustomerInfo customerInfo)
        {
            // get the order from the cache
            var newOrderId = HttpContext.Session.Get<Guid>("NewOrderId");
            var order = GetNewCustomerOrder(newOrderId);    

            // update customer info on order
            order.CustomerInfo = customerInfo;

            // update the order in the cache
            var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                    .SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
            _cache.Set("NewOrderId" + newOrderId, order, cacheEntryOptions);

            return PartialView("_ReviewOrder", order);
        }
```

**Here's the javascript/ajax.**

```
$("#customerInfoForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if ($("#customerInfoForm").valid() == false) { // check if the form is valid
        return false; 
    } else { // form is valid
        var customerInfo = $("#customerInfoForm").serializeArray();
        // hide other tabs
        $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active");
        $(".tab-pane").removeClass("show");
        $(".nav-link").removeClass("active");
        // show review tab
        $("#nav-tab-reviewOrder").addClass("active");
        $("#nav-tab-reviewOrder").addClass("show");
        $("#nav-link-reviewOrder").addClass("active");

        $("#tabColumn").addClass("w-100");
        $("#cartColumn").attr("hidden", true);
        $(".nav-link").attr("disabled", true);
        $(".nav-link").addClass("disabled");

        // get the review tab partial
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ServiceOrder/Review',
            data: customerInfo,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                $('#reviewOrderPartialView').html(response);  // response contains the html from the partial view

                // get the cart for review order
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Cart/Show',
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#cartReviewPartialView').html(response);  // response contains the html from the partial view
                        // disable cart buttons
                        $(".cs-RemoveFromCartButton").attr("disabled", true);
                        $(".cs-RemoveFromCartButton").attr("hidden", true);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $('#cartReviewPartialView').html('Cart failed to load');  
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#reviewOrderPartialView').html('Review Order failed to load');  
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: What does your `Controller` look like?

Comment: @MetroSmurf I've added the methods above

Comment: Have you used `@Html.Partial("_ValidationScriptsPartial")` in your view?And can you share how you use ajax to submit the form?

Comment: Looks like the `Review` action needs to invoke `ModelState.IsValid` to perform the validation. In the link you provided, check out the [Top-level node validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#top-level-node-validation) topic.

Comment: @MetroSmurf I'm a little confused by this documentation; the Top-level node validation appears to put the logic and messaging in the controller, but the IValidatableObject has this already in the model.  I'm not understanding how the two are supposed to work together.

Comment: @YiyiYou Sorry, I overlooked your comment.  I've added the ajax to my question above.